# Why addEventListener doesn't get global var?

Tags: javascript, html

Why "multiply" button works only if I put both `var` into function, but not with global `var`?

Here are my codes:

```js
var first = document.getElementById("firstN").value;
var second = document.getElementById("secondN").value;

document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = first * second;
});
```

```html
<p>1st Number: <input id="firstN" type="number"></p>
<p>2nd Number: <input id="secondN" type="number"></p>
<button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide">Divide</button>
<p>The result is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your question, but `first` and `second` are only set once, before the clock handler is even setup.

Comment: Please provide more info. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the initial `.value` of the input…? Nothing. You assign that to `first`. You're never getting the value of the input ever again. That's why.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to find out the values of `first` and `second` when you clicked the button.

```
document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var first = document.getElementById("firstN").value;
    var second = document.getElementById("secondN").value;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = first * second; 
});
```

```js
 document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var first = document.getElementById("firstN").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("secondN").value;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = first * second;
    });
```

```html
<p>1st Number: <input id="firstN" type="number"></p>
<p>2nd Number: <input id="secondN" type="number"></p>
<button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide">Divide</button>
<p>The result is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the variables `first` and `second` out of the event handler you most select only the elements (In this example I use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

```
var first = document.querySelector('#firstN');
var second = document.querySelector('#secondN');
```

Check in the answer that using [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can select multiple elements to attach at once the `click` event handler.. and access to the elements `value` attribute with in the function handler to solve **Multiply** and **Divide** in one method.

Code example:

```js
var first = document.querySelector('#firstN');
var second = document.querySelector('#secondN');
        
document
  .querySelectorAll('#multiply, #divide')
  .forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var result =  {
          'multiply': first.value * second.value,
          'divide': first.value / second.value
        };
        document.querySelector('#answer').innerHTML = result[elem.id];
    });
  });
```

```html
<p>1st Number: <input id="firstN" type="number"></p>
<p>2nd Number: <input id="secondN" type="number"></p>
<button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide">Divide</button>
<p>The result is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Notice that as explained by [@Alexandru-Ionut Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6583140/alexandru-ionut-mihai) the value of the variables `first` and `second` should be assigned with in the event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the page loads and parses it stores the value of variables, `first` and `second` which is `null` at the moment.

So you have to declare or assign values to them inside the `click` event in order to assign the values of inputs into the variables. 
Also the format of the input by default in dom is `string`, so you have to handle it too, by using the `parseInt`/`parseFloat` methods which will change the `string` to `numbers`.

```js
document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var first = document.getElementById("firstN").value;
  var second = document.getElementById("secondN").value;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = parseFloat(first) * parseFloat(second);
});
```

```html
<p>1st Number: <input id="firstN" type="number"></p>
<p>2nd Number: <input id="secondN" type="number"></p>
<button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide">Divide</button>
<p>The result is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

For more information you can refer to these articles:

1. [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) / [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
2. [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) / [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
3. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set value of first and second inside addEventListner.

```js
window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var first = document.getElementById("firstN").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("secondN").value;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = first * second;
    });
}
```

```html
<p>1st Number: <input id="firstN" type="number"></p>
<p>2nd Number: <input id="secondN" type="number"></p>
<button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
<button id="divide">Divide</button>
<p>The result is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Please add more clarity to question if you are looking for some different answer.